# Probabilties of success on dice

Tags: binomial-distribution, dice

I’m trying to learn about what type of equations do I need to calculate some probabilties of dice:

1- Calculate the probabily of obtaining a 6 or more in 10 faced dice thrown 8 times.

2- Calculate the average of succeses when trowing a 10 faced dice 8 times (a succes consists of obtaing a 6 or more on the dice).

Any idea on what should I start learning?

Comment: (1) Does a "10 faced dice" have 10 sides labelled 1,2,...,10? (2) Are you looking at the *sum* of the eight rolls?

Comment: What is the difference between questions 1 and 2?

Comment: I think question $2$ means if you get $1,1,1,1,6,7,7,8$ then the average is $a= {6+7+7+8\over 4}$. He wants to know the expected value of $a$.

Comment: I would argue by complete symmetry of $6,7,8,9,10$ the expected value must be $8$, although this is not rigorous.

Comment: in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3687456/given-a-deck-of-cards-what-are-the-odds-of-consecutively-drawing-higher-cards-f/3687546#3687546) you can find some bibliography for an introduction to these questions

Comment: Question is confusing.  It looks to me that it is the same as a coin flip.  6 or more is heads, 1 to 5 is tails.